# Find the center of mass of the body bounded by $z=0$ and $z=H-x^2-y^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

First I switched to cylindrical coordinate system: $0 \leq z \leq H - r^2$.

This is the mass of the body:

$$\int_0^H\int_{-\sqrt{H-z}}^{\sqrt{H-z}}\int_0^{2\pi}r\,d\phi \,dr \,dz = \frac43\frac25\pi H^{\frac52}$$

Now the other thing:

$$\int_0^H\int_{-\sqrt{H-z}}^{\sqrt{H-z}}\int_0^{2\pi}r z \,d\phi \,dr \,dz = \frac43\frac25\frac27\pi H^{\frac72}$$

And $$C_z = \frac{\frac43\frac25\frac27\pi H^{\frac72}}{\frac43\frac25\pi H^{\frac52}} = \frac27 H$$

However my teacher says the asnwer is $\frac{H}{3}$. Where is the mistake? Is there an easier way to calculate this (maybe simpler integrals)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower limits of the $r$-integrals are incorrect: they should just be zero. Putting that aside, you've made errors computing the integrals you presented. They should be proportional to $H^2$ and $H^3$, not $H^{5/2}$ and $H^{7/2}$. The mass of the solid is 
$$\int_0^H \int_0^{\sqrt{H - z}} \int_0^{2\pi} r\, d\phi\, dr\, dz = \int_0^H \int_0^{\sqrt{H-z}} 2\pi r\, dr\, dz = \int_0^H \pi(H - z)\, dz = \frac{\pi H^2}{2}$$
and the moment integral is 
$$\int_0^H \int_0^{\sqrt{H-z}} \int_0^{2\pi} zr\, d\phi\, dr\, dz = \int_0^H \int_0^{\sqrt{H-z}} 2\pi rz\, dr\, dz = \int_0^H \pi z(H-z)\, dz = \frac{\pi H^3}{6}$$ Therefore, 
$$C_z =\frac{\pi H^3/6}{\pi H^2/2} = \frac{H}{3}$$ as your teacher claimed.